# Is there a hubot command to see who's in the channel?

Tags: hubot

I want a list of all of the people in the current channel.

How can I get this with `hubot`?

Comment: Channel in what? IRC?  Hubot can connect to lots of things

Comment: Yes, IRC is what I'm referring to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least you can try `channellist_item` in [IRC API](https://node-irc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/API.html), it states

> Emitted for each channel the server returns. The channel_info object
>   contains keys ‘name’, ‘users’ (number of users on the channel), and
>   ‘topic’.

Answer (score 0):

No - it seems that it's not possible. The best `hubot` can do is track as people enter and leave the channel, but there's no simple command to get all current people.